# How to handle the scales with d3.drag in a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

I tried to implement a scatter plot with a drag behaviour in D3 but I don't understand how to handle the scaling with the dragging effect.

For now I did this :

https://bl.ocks.org/AlexisPister/c60d570d6739a28dfd8ba0c9eae76866/518dc76870582d2fb8d43609e320e91cb246c19d

As I understand, there is two coordinate systems : the one of the objects I want to draw (each object is described by an x and y coordinate both following a normal law), and the one of the canvas which is displayed. The d3.scale objects allow to map between the two.

So first, to find the objects which are dragged from the coordinates of the d3.event object, I loop over all the data array and find which object has their scaled coordinates equals to the d3.event's x and y.

Then I modify this object coordinates with the d3.event coordinates, inverse transformed with the scale objects to map from the canvas coordinate system to the objects coordinate system.

However, this does not work : when a point is dragged, it moves but not where the cursor is. I don't understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know the mouse position and apply it to the current x and y.
Did some changes, have a look at `mousePosition`, you need a little more work to make it perfect, but you will get the idee

```js
    let width = 960,
        height = 500,
        radius = 3,
        transform = d3.zoomIdentity
    
    let canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)

    let ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
    
    let data = d3.range(200)
           .map(() => { return {"x": d3.randomNormal()(),
                                       "y": d3.randomNormal()()}})
    
    let scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.x}))
            .range([0, width])
    
    let scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.y}))
            .range([height, 0])
    
    //canvas.call(d3.zoom()
    //              .on("zoom", zoomed))
    
    canvas.call(d3.drag()
                  .subject(dragSubject)
                  .on("drag", dragged))
    
    function zoomed(){
      transform = d3.event.transform
      render()
    }
    
    function dragSubject(){
   
     x = d3.event.x 
      y = d3.event.y
      

      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        point = data[i]
        dx = x - scaleX(point.x)  
        dy = y - scaleY(point.y) 

        if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius * radius){          
          return data[i];
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    // get the position of the mouse, you need to calculate scale to
    function mousePosition(event) {
            if (event == undefined || (!event.pageX && !event.offsetX))
             return {x:0, y:0}
            return { x: event.pageX || event.offsetX, y: event.pageY || event.offsetY };
        };
    
    function dragged(){
      
      var mouse = mousePosition(window.event)
      d3.event.subject.x = scaleX.invert(d3.event.x + (mouse.x)) 
      d3.event.subject.y = scaleY.invert(d3.event.y + mouse.y) 
   

      render()
    }
    
    function render(){
      ctx.save()
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
      
      ctx.beginPath()
      //ctx.translate(transform.x, transform.y)
      //ctx.scale(transform.k, transform.k)
      
      data.forEach(function(d){
        ctx.moveTo(scaleX(d.x) + radius, scaleY(d.y))
        ctx.arc(scaleX(d.x), scaleY(d.y), radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
      })
      ctx.stroke()
      
      /*
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height) */
      
      ctx.restore()
    }
    
    render()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Comment: But are not d3.event.x and d3.event.y supposed to give the coordinates of the mouse ?

Comment: hmm not really its the position of the figure realated to the canvas and not the whole webside. window.event.pagex is the mouse position that are calculated based on the whole website. not sure if i made you understand. do you see the pictiure ?

Comment: It's the postion related to the canvas that I want because I draw the objects related to the canvas. It seems that d3.event.x does not output this but something else, I don't know what. I resolved my problem using d3.mouse in the end

Comment: ok good to know, it may be usefull to look at this canvas i made a while ago https://github.com/AlenToma/Canvas-Mask/blob/master/lbMask.js. it have drag